# Установить лист в гугл таблице при заливке данных!

Tags: java, google-spreadsheet

интересует вопрос как установить лист при записи данных в гугл таблицу с помощью java, по умолчанию sheetid = 0 и данные пишутся в первый лист, возможно ли как то установить лист используя его идентификатор (sheetid) 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/ **spreadsheetId** /edit#gid= **sheetid**

```
 public static void executeReloadingToGoogleSheetsAppend(List<List<Object>> execute, String spreadsheetId, String sheetId ) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    ValueRange vr = new ValueRange().setValues(execute);
    Sheets sheet = new SheetsServiceAuth().getSheetsService();

    sheet.spreadsheets().values()
            .append(spreadsheetId, "A2", vr)
            .setValueInputOption("USER_ENTERED")

            .setInsertDataOption("INSERT_ROWS")
            .setIncludeValuesInResponse(true)
            .execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не уверен, что существует такой метод в API. Скорее всего вам потребуется два вызова для обновления данных по `gid` листа. Т.о. для начала вы должны получить экземпляр [Spreadsheets](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#Spreadsheet)

```
Sheets.Spreadsheets.Get request = sheetsService.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId);
```

В котором будет массив листов. Из которого и берется соответствие gid -- sheet name.

В вашем же примере диапазон обновления следует передать в нотации A1, указывая лист назначения по имени. Например, `Sheet1!A2`, `'Yet another sheet'!A2`.

Позволю себе заметить неудачный выбор имени переменной. Возможно, `Sheets sheetsService = getSheetsService();` было бы куда понятнее.